# File existence check in windows phone 8 app

Tags: file, windows-phone-8

I have some files in the **shared/transfers/** folder in my windows phone 8 app. Now i need to check the existence of those file. I used this method.

```
File.Exists("shared/transfers/" + fileName);
```

But this method always returns false even if the file is currently there. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works

```
string fileName = "/shared/transfers/filename";
string localPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName); 
if (await File.FileExistsInPath(localPath))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you :) 

I think instead of using File.FileExistsInPath(localPath),you can use File.Exists() method too.

Comment: Haven't tried that out yet but will do. Thanks for accepting as answer! Cheers!